# Retrofit POST with empty array

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to send a POST with Retrofit:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
  .addConverterFactory(
      GsonConverterFactory.create(
          GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()
      ))
  .client(okHttpClient)
  .build()
```

```
    @POST(endpoint)
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun partialPickupsDelivery(
            @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>,
            @Field("userId") userId: String,
            @Field("purchaseIds[]") purchases: ArrayList<String>
    ): Call<ResponseBody>
```

The server is waiting something like this:
`purchaseIds=["1234", "2345", "3456"]`

The problem comes when I try to send an empty array (not null) because the server is waiting:
`purchaseIds=[]`
But I'm sending only the first param `userId` (I think retrofit is removing the second one because the array is empty).

Is there any way to send `purchaseIds=[]`?

Thx

Comment: Can you show how this function `partialPickupsDelivery` is called?

Comment: `@Field("purchaseIds[]")` this is not the way of calling array.

Comment: Try this @Field("purchaseIds") purchases = emptyList<String>

Comment: service.partialPickupsDelivery(
       headers,
       userId,
       purchaseId
)
where headers: Map<String, String>
userId: String
purchaseIds: ArrayList<String>

Comment: @CôngHải: at the request is still removed this field

Comment: No, it keeps this field empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works for me:

```
@POST(endpoint)
fun partialPickupsDelivery(
   @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>,
   @Body params: HashMap<String, Any>
): Call<ResponseBody?>
```

where `params` is:

```
val params = HashMap<String, Any>().apply {
    this["purchaseIds"] = destinationsId
    this["userId"] = deliverId
}
```

and it's called this way:

```
val call: Call<ResponseBody> =
      service.partialPickupsDelivery(
          headers,
          params
      )
```

I hope this can help someone

Answer (score 0):

you can use `List` instead of `ArrayList`